# Find and return by reference in STL map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I have a class with those two public methods:

```
void StateManager::setEntityState(const EntityCTCId id, const EntityCTCState state) {
    auto it = entities.find(id);
    if(it != entities.end())
        it->second.state = state;
    else
        entities.emplace(id, EntityCTC{id, state});
}

EntityCTCState StateManager::getEntityState(const EntityCTCId id) const {
    auto it = entities.find(id);
    if(it != entities.end())
        return it->second.state;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Entity CTC [" << id << "] NOT found!";
    throw EntityCTCNotFound{ss.str()};
}
```

Where `entities` is a `std::map<EntityCTCId, EntityCTC>`.

I would like to refactor those methods to isolate the common `find` and return by reference the found `EntityCTC`, but I cannot figure out how to handle the case of "key not found":

```
EntityCTC& findEntity(const EntityCTCId id) {
    auto it = entities.find(id);
    if(it != entities.end())
        return it->second.state;
    else
        // ???
}
```

The only solution I found is to throw the exception inside this new method, but that implies to use a `try-catch` inside `setEntityState` to discriminate between update and new insert (and I read that exception management should not be used as logical branch but only for error management).

Could you suggest me any other approach?

Comment: Seems to me you are over-refactoring. I don't see a problem with calling find() on the same map in two different functions if the goal is different in each of them.

Comment: How about: bool findEntity(const EntityCTCId id, EntityCTC &state) ? What's more, returning a reference is not a good practice, because the id might be removed from entities.

Comment: What's wrong with using `entities.at` for get, and StoryTeller's suggestion (or `operator[]`) for set? Why is `EntityCTCNotFound` constructed from a `std::string` and not an `EntityCTCId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to make full use of the API. For you see, [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) has a return value. It's a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`. The iterator can be used to access the item under the key, and the bool is to let you know if an insertion happened or the key already existed in the map.

Therefore, I suggest you just re-write `setEntityState`:

```
void StateManager::setEntityState(const EntityCTCId id, const EntityCTCState state) {
    auto status = entities.emplace(id, EntityCTC{id, state});
    if(!status.second)
      status.first->second.state = state;
}
```

And now there is no common functionality to worry about, and you do only a single O(logN) operation in the function instead of two.

---

Addendum, since you may worry about the cost of constructing the value and not as part of premature optimization. Another point about using the API to the fullest is to know there is way to piece-wise construct the pair that is inserted into the map. Like this:

```
auto status = entities.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                               std::forward_as_tuple(id),
                               std::forward_as_tuple(id, state));
```

Comment: But now you have the overhead of always constructing an `EntityCTC` even if not necessary.

Comment: @nwp - Do I? Copy elision is a thing.

Comment: Yes. In the case when the given `id` already exists in `entities` the original code doesn't create an `EntityCTC` while yours does. Copy elision doesn't get you out of that.

Comment: @nwp - I don't know how simple the OP's state is, so what you are saying *could* be premature optimization. But anyhow, we can just piecewise construct the pair if required.

Comment: why not just use `operator[]`?

Comment: @Caleth - Requires a default c'tor. Didn't want to assume.